# Adding facebook invite on my website

Tags: facebook, fbml

i have a website www.skoola.com , i want to add facebook invite (to enable site visitors invite their friends).

I have read a good no of docs aon facebook and other sites on ow to do it, but i cant get it right.

Please anybody that has done should kindly explain the steps and code samples necessary to get it fixed (i hv tried pasting the codes available on facebook on my website, yet it gives me a blank page).

Pls assist ive been on this for close to a week

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very good tutorial for FB-App development in general: http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/index You could start with the 2nd set of tutorials to get an overview.

The part you are looking for (invitations) is here: http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/jssdk/learning_jssdk_11.html - should work on copy/paste but i´d recommend reading the other tutorials ... just to be on the save side ;-)

Comment: tnks bt the links are nt goin thru, pls confirm links for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form

or

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/serverFbml

Comment: ive tried out those example codes (i even did again now), i still get a blank page. pls ,kindly tk time to explain the steps to me.